# Doodle jump unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So look: I have a monster in the game that when player collides with him a panel appears and says try again.
There is now a shield object, that will protect the player from death, so when the player collides with it and then if you touch the monster you shouldn't die for one time: it will be like that, you touch the shield and you are protected from one death. Can you help me write this code?

```
public GameObject panel;
public bool hasShield = false; /* no shield in the beginning */    

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Shield") 
    {
        hasShield = true; //We are safe now.
        /* TODO: StartCoroutine() or Invoke() to reset the variable and the graphic effect after some amount of time. */
    }
    else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Monster" && !hasShield) 
    { 
        //We hit a monster and had no shield. Display gameover.
        panel.SetActive (true);
    }
    //I assume the panel is inactive by default so no need to call SetActive(false) on it.
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Can you describe your logic better? When exactly is the panel supposed to be activated or deactivated?

Comment: The panel needs to be activated after i touch the monster, but if i touch the shield and then the monster then the panel should not appear

Answer (score 5):

The inside of this code can never be reached:

```
     if (col.gameObject.tag == "Shield") 
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Monster")
        {
            panel.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

For the first `if` check to pass, the tag *must* be "Shield", however for the second test to pass, it must be "Monster". These two conditions cannot be true at the same time, the code is equivalent to

```
 if(col.gameObject.tag == "Shield" && col.gameObject.tag == "Monster")
```

However, if you replace `&&` with `||` (logical OR) in the expression above, you will get your desired results. So, the rewritten code would be

```
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Monster") 
    { 
        panel.SetActive (true);
    }
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Shield" || col.gameObject.tag == "Monster") 
    {
         panel.SetActive(false);
    }
```

The inside code will now trigger if the is "Shield" **or** "Monster".

EDIT:
As we've talked about it in the comments, the logic was flawed overall. Now according to your description

> The panel needs to be activated after i touch the monster, but if i touch the shield and then the monster then the panel should not appear

I advise the following: When a shield is collected, save this to some variable, like

```
bool hasShield;
```

And set it to `true` when the shield is collected. Then, if you hit something, check if it is a monster AND if you don't have a shield, then you see the "Game Over" screen. So alltogether the player should look something like

```
    public GameObject panel;
    public bool hasShield = false; /* no shield in the beginning */    

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Shield") 
        {
             hasShield = true; //We are safe now.
             /* TODO: StartCoroutine() or Invoke() to reset the variable and the graphic effect after some amount of time. */
        }
        else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Monster") 
        { 
            if(!hasShield)
                panel.SetActive (true);  //We hit a monster and had no shield. Display gameover.

            else
                hasShield = false; //loose the shield
        }
        //I assume the panel is inactive by default so no need to call SetActive(false) on it.
    }
```

Comment: Not bad - you typed that out in two and a half minutes! `:-O`

Comment: @halfer Had the priviledge of seeing the question when it was just 30secs old :)

Comment: While using the OR operator would make the code accessible, I don't think it would achieve the goal. Would that not make it so `panel.SetActive(false)` will be called every time regardless of a shield being present?

Comment: You're right, the logic is even more "disturbing"... The first if statement already checks for "Monster", checking it again and doing the opposite operation does't make sense. That was just the first logical mistake I've seen, I jumped to a conclusion too fast. This is not a completly correct answer.

Comment: It looks like the logic is based on a flawed premise, i haven't done any game dev myself but I would imagine you need something in addition to the tag property to track if a shield is active.

Comment: hey, oh so many responses, look i will try this and then tell you if it works!

Comment: now, when i touch the monster and the shield the panel never opens again, but it should open if i touch just the monster but if i touch the shield and the monster than not, now it is never opening!

Comment: Tell me a better logic!

Comment: @MelinceanuVictor Take a look at my advice now.

Comment: now, when i touch the monster and the shield the panel never opens again, but it should open if i touch just the monster but if i touch the shield and the monster than not, now it is never opening!

Comment: Then I don't understand your game good enough. Post the scene layout and the gameobjects and their tags in your original question. My general advice should be good though.

Comment: ok, man may be it will vbe better if you take a look through team viewer?

Comment: No personal support. Ask a good and well defined question, and you will receive good answers.

Comment: So look: I have a monster in the game that when player collides with him a panel appears and says try again.

Comment: There is now a shield object, that will protect the player from death, so when the player collides with it and then if you touch the monster you shouldn't die for one time: it will be like that, you touch the shield and you are protected from one death. Can you help me write this code?

Comment: It's basically the bottom code from the answer, but with another `else if` like `else if(col.gameObject.tag == "Monster" && hasShield) { hasShield = false; }`

Comment: when i touch the shield and then a monster the ffirst time it doesn't show up the panel but second it shows up the try again panel, is actually what i needed, is this a lag or where this code meant to work?

Comment: No actually it still doesn't work, is the same like before

Comment: if i touch then i die

Comment: may be some other idea?

Comment: Don't spam the comment section, write all that information in your original information then other people can help you, too.

Comment: You have that `if(col.gameObject.tag == "Shield") { ... } else if(col.gameObject.tag == "Monster" && !hasShield) { ... } else if(col.gameObject.tag == "Monster" && hasShield) { ... }` now?

Comment: you guys are great thanks for helping but still let's finish!

Comment: Again, please edit your opening question and provide your current code so we are up to date.

Comment: Ok, so that is not what I asked if you have done. You need to add `else if(col.gameObject.tag == "Monster" && hasShield) { hasShield = false; }` to that. Note that the first else if says `!hasShield` and the second `hasShield`.

Comment: Oh yes, reset it to `false` ofcourse. I just talked about a timeout, but if you hit a monster you should also loose the shield immediatly, I can only guess that's what you wanted. Code edited again.

Comment: I will doo now, sorry i slept

Comment: one question, if i add that line of code, should i add it instead of  the else if statement, if yes then where to add the panel setactive(falsle) or true, because it can't appear

Comment: and i don't get the logic you say else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Monster" && !hasShield) 
  { 
   panel.SetActive (true);
  }"

Comment: that means, if i touch the monster and shield is on, then the panl neeeds to appear? why should i die if i have the shield?

Comment: if the panel appears tha tmeans that i die!

Comment: man, look, it doesn't work at all, can you propose something else?

Comment: done, i have repaired everything this is the code that works!

Answer (score 0):

this is the corect code!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class DestroyPlayerOnTouch : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject panel;
       bool hasshield = false;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
          if (col.gameObject.tag == "Monster"  && !hasshield) 
        { 
            panel.SetActive (true);
        }

        else if(col.gameObject.tag == "Monster" && hasshield)
        {
            panel.SetActive (false);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Shield") 
        {
            Debug.Log("hasshield!");
            hasshield = true;
        }
    }
}
```